# Creating reusable WPFToolkit controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit

I would like to create a reusable WPFToolkit IntegerUpDown so I do not need to copy and paste the same style with triggers on different bindings over and over again.

I've attempted to use DataTemplates but I'm unsure where I can provide the source for the IntegerUpDown component when I provide the template.

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Person.Age.Value}">
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:IntegerUpDown}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Person.Age.DataDirty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Person.Age.DataDirty}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </xctk:IntegerUpDown.Style>
</xctk:IntegerUpDown>
```

Is there a way that this component can be generic enough so it can be applied  similarly to:

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown
    Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource Person.Age}}"
    Template="{StaticResource myPersonInfo}"/>
```